Why do some React Native API module functions need () and others dont?
For example, in the Easing module https://reactnative.dev/docs/easing,
both the 'bounce' and 'elastic' are standard methods with default values.
Calling Easing.bounce works, but not Easing.bounce()
Conversely, Easing.elastic() works, but not Easing.elastic
Why is that the case?
I've looked over the documentation and could not find any explanation as to why.

The question should be "why are some functions named with verbs (bounce) while others are named with nouns (elastic) ?" These frameworks make no semantic sense

Easing.bounce and Easing.elastic both take a single numeric parameter, but that parameter means different things to the two functions.
Easing.bounce takes a single number t, representing time - how far along in the animation we are. It returns the value appropriate for the given time.
In contrast, Easing.elastic takes a single number bounciness, representing how bouncy the animation should be. Calling this function returns a new function, that works like Easing.bounce does - the new function takes an input representing a time, and returns a value for that time.
Easing.elastic isn't really an easing function. It's a function that makes easing functions. If you pass Easing.elastic where an easing function is expected, it won't work. You need to call Easing.elastic and pass the returned easing function.
It may help to read the source code. You can see there that Easing.bounce returns a number, and Easing.elastic returns a function.

"elastic" should be named "createElastic" if it is a factory that creates and return an elastic easing.

Thanks for linking the src code and sorry if I'm reading it wrong, but rather than returning a new function, isn't elastic just calling that function and returning it's return value? In which case they should both be returning both returning a number

@JonB.: No. It is returning the new function. return t => 1 - Math.pow(Math.cos((t * Math.PI) / 2), 3) * Math.cos(t * p); returns a function.
